# Python - command line argument extracted as a string ImportError

Tags: python, import, command-line-arguments, importerror, argv

I am trying to do the following:

In  CMD:

`python __main__.py 127.0.0.1`

The in **main**.py:

`address = sys.argv[1]`

Then in my config.py file, I am importing the address like this:

```
from __main__.py import address

...

EXAMPLE_URL = f"http://{address}/login"
```

And I am using the URL in a simple test scenario, which is imported from config and I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'address' from '__main__' (__main__.py)
```

This is my directory structure:

```
QA System/
├── config/
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── .... some other unneccessary stuff
└── tests/
    ├── test_scenarios
       ├── test_scenario_01.py
       ├── test_scenario_02.py
       ├── __init__.py
    |── test_suite.py
    |── __init__.py
|
|-- __main__.py   < --- I launch tests from here
|-- __init__.py
```

It seems the error is in config file during the imports, but I cannot understand where the error is. Thanks in advance!

**main**.py file:

```
import argparse
import sys

from tests.test_suite import runner

if __name__ == "__main__":
    address = str(sys.argv[1])
    runner()   # This runs the tests, and the tests also use config.py for
                 various settings, I am worried something happens with the
                 imports there.
```

Comment: is adress define in __main__.py ??

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited my post - I used file.py at first, and forgot to re-edit it in the end.

Comment: Is the variable address in top-level scope?

Comment: Where are you initialising the `address`? Is it inside a function or is it global?

Comment: I have posted my __main__.py. I am initialising it in the if __name__=="__main__" part of the code. However, I am worried that it may happen because the runner() bit imports config for the tests, and later config imports from __main__, so it becomes like a circular import.

Comment: Looks like address is not set when main.py is imported by config... Perhaps it is circular.. Why not use pytest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [circular import](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/)

When you import a module in Python, say, `import __main__` as in your example, a `module` object is created for the namespace of the module, which is initially empty.  Then, as the code in the body of the module is executed--variables assigned, functions and classes defined, etc. that namespace gets filled in in order.  E.g. take the following script:

```
$ cat a.py
print(locals())
an_int = 1

print("after an_int = 1")
print(locals())

def a_func(): pass
print("after def a_func(): pass")
print(locals())
```

Then run it:

```
$ python a.py
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__file__': 'a.py', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
after an_int = 1
{'an_int': 1, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'a.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
after def a_func(): pass
{'an_int': 1, 'a_func': <function a_func at 0x6ffffeed758>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'a.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

You can see the namespace gets filled in line-by-line.

Now say we modify it like:

```
$ cat a.py
print(locals())
an_int = 1

print("after an_int = 1")
print(locals())

import b
print("after import b")

def a_func(): pass
print("after def a_func(): pass")
print(locals())
```

and add `b.py`:

```
$ cat b.py
import sys
print('a is in progress of being imported:', sys.modules['a'])
print("is a_func defined in a? `'a_func' in sys.modules['a'].__dict__`:",
      'a_func' in sys.modules['a'].__dict__)
from a import a_func
```

and run it like:

```
python -c 'import a'
```

You'll get some output ending in a Traceback:

```
...
after an_int = 1
{'an_int': 1, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'a.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
a is in progress of being imported: <module 'a' from '/path/to/a.py'>
is a_func defined in a? `'a_func' in sys.modules['a'].__dict__`: False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "a.py", line 7, in <module>
    import b
  File "b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a import a_func
ImportError: cannot import name 'a_func'
```

If however you move `import b` to after the definition of `a_func`:

```
$ cat a.py
print(locals())
an_int = 1

print("after an_int = 1")
print(locals())

def a_func(): pass
print("after def a_func(): pass")
print(locals())

import b
print("after import b")
```

And again run `python -c 'import a'` you'll see it works, and the output ends with "after import b".

**BONUS QUESTION**: Why did I run `python -c 'import a'` and not just `python a.py`?  If you try the latter, the previous version will actually *work* and will appear to import `a.py` twice.  This is because when you run `python somemodule.py` it is not imported initially as `somemodule`, but rather as `__main__`.  So from the import system's perspective the `a` module has not been imported yet when running `from a import a_func`.  A very confusing caveat.

---

So in your case if you have something like `__main__.py`:

```
import config
address = 1
```

and in `config.py`:

```
from __main__ import address
```

when you run `python __main__.py`, by the time it runs `import config`, `address` isn't assigned yet, so the code in `config` that tries to import `address` from `__main__` results in an `ImportError`.

In your case it's a little more complicated because you aren't importing `config` directly in `__main__` from what it looks like, but indirectly that's still what's happening.

In this case, you shouldn't be passing variables around between modules by way of import statements.  In fact, `__main__` should really just be a command-line front-end to your code, and the rest of your code should be able to work independently from it (e.g. a good design would allow you to run `from tests.test_runner import runner` and call `runner()` from an interactive Python prompt, in principle, even if you never actually use it that way).

So instead make `runner(...)` take *arguments* for whatever options it requires.  Then `__main__.py` would just take those arguments from command-line arguments.  E.g.:

```
def runner(address=None):
    # Or maybe just runner(address) if you don't want to make the
    # address argument optional
```

Then

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    address = sys.argv[1]  # Use argparse instead if you can
    runner(address=address)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a circular dependency here.   Your  `__main__` isn't directly importing  `config` but my guess is that the runner is. basically if you import  `config` before you hit the `address = str(sys.argv[1])` line your going to hit this issue.

I think a better way to do this is to go with a structure like this:

config.py

`URL_TEMPLATE = ""http://{}/login"`

then in `__main__.py`

```
from config import URL_TEMPLATE

url = URL_TEMPLATE.format(address)
```

this keeps only the static stuff in config and the dynamic runtime generated final url in your main